# c++ std::out_of_range at memory location

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a basic calculator where the user can enter 2 numbers and an operator and the calculation will work. I can't figure out why I am getting this error and I am not entirely sure what this error means because I am new to c++ having only had experience with some java.

Here is what I have:

Calculation.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculation{
private:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Calculation();
    int calculateAddition(int, int);
    int calculateSubtraction(int, int);
    int calculateMultiplication(int, int);
    int calculateDivision(int, int);
};
```

Calculation.cpp

```
#include "Calculation.h"

Calculation::Calculation(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

int Calculation::calculateAddition(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}

int Calculation::calculateSubtraction(int x, int y){
    return x - y;
}

int Calculation::calculateMultiplication(int x, int y){
    return x * y;
}

int Calculation::calculateDivision(int x, int y){
    return x / y;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Calculation.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
Calculation calc;
int i = 0;
char k;
int x;
int y;
char j = 'a';
string inputCalc;
stringstream str;

while(j != 'q'){
    cout << "1. Make Calculation" << endl;
    cout << "2. Quit" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    if(i == 1){
        cout << "Input calculation:" << endl;
        cin >> inputCalc;
        k = inputCalc.at(2);
        str << inputCalc.at(1);
        str >> x;
        str << inputCalc.at(3);
        str >> y;
        if (k == '+'){
            calc.calculateAddition(x, y);
        }
        else if (k == '-'){
            calc.calculateSubtraction(x, y);
        }
        else if (k == '*'){
            calc.calculateMultiplication(x, y);
        }
        else if (k == '/'){
            calc.calculateDivision(x, y);
        }
        else{
        }
    }
    else if(i == 2){
        j = 'q';
    }
    else{
        cout << "Invalid input. Please enter 1 or 2." << endl;
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Ahhh thank you, I forgot that everything starts from 0. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the input in `cin >> inputCalc` to be '1+2'. `input.at(0)=='1'`, `input.at(1)=='+'` and `input.at(2)==2`. input.at(3) is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error occurs in some of the statements as this

```
str << inputCalc.at(3);
```

Are you sure that inputCalc has at least four characters that this statement will be valid? Take into account that valid range of indecies is [0, length() - 1]

std::out_of_range is a standard exception that is thrown by std::string member function at().